# What are sibling imports?

Tags: python, python-import

[2to3 - Automated Python 2 to 3 code translation - Fixers - import](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html#2to3fixer-import) note that:

> Detects sibling imports and converts them to relative imports.

Comment: I am glad that 2to3.py can fix this sibling import which is implicit relative import actually now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/lib2to3/fixes/fix_import.py#L1-L11):

> ```
> """Fixer for import statements.
> If spam is being imported from the local directory, this import:
>     from spam import eggs
> Becomes:
>     from .spam import eggs
> And this import:
>     import spam
> Becomes:
>     from . import spam
> """
> ```

So *sibling* would stand for *"on the same level"*.

Answer (score 2):

*Sibling import* is **not** a terminus technicus. In the context of your question it means:

- Importing a *file* from the *same directory* (so the *importing* file and the *imported* one are **siblings** relative to the file system), or
- Importing a module (modules) from *such a file*.

---

*Note:*

The problem rose from the small difference between Python 2 and Python 3 import systems, but let first compare file system paths with packages/modules paths used in  the `import` or `from ... import` statements:

```
+---+--------------------------+-------------------------+
|   |    In the File system    |   In the Python import  |
+---+--------------------------+-------------------------+
| 1 | /doc/excel               |  doc.excel              | <--- absolute
| 2 |   excel (we are in /doc) |   excel (we are in doc) | <--- ???
| 3 | ./excel (we are in /doc) |  .excel (we are in doc) | <--- relative
+---+--------------------------+-------------------------+
```

The substantial difference is this:

*In file systems we always recognize the **absolute** path as a path which begins with `/` (or something similar)*, so cases 2 and 3 in the previous table have *the same meaning* - both are **relative** paths.

But in the *Python import system*, case 2 means: search for `excel` in the current module (i.e in `doc`), *but if it is not found, consider it as the top-level module*. And this can make problems.

The `2to3.py` analyses such ambiguous (case 2's) imports, tries to determine which of them are *siblings ones* (in the meaning mentioned at top of this answer), and converts them to be *unambiguously relative ones (i. e. into case 3's)*.

(Case 3 is *always unambiguous* - leading `.` means the *relative* path, i. e. the module `doc.excel`).

Answer (score 1):

```
"""Fixer for import statements.
If spam is being imported from the local directory, this import:
    from spam import eggs
Becomes:
    from .spam import eggs
And this import:
    import spam
Becomes:
    from . import spam
"""
```

it will change when import local module  and have a `__init__.py` in local

```
-- local path
  -- a.py
  -- b.py
  -- __init__.py


RefactoringTool: Refactored a.py
--- a.py    (original)
+++ a.py    (refactored)
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
-import b
-print 'xxx'
+from . import b
+print('xxx')
RefactoringTool: Files that need to be modified:
RefactoringTool: a.py
```

detail see:[probably_a_local_import](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/lib2to3/fixes/fix_import.py#L85)

Answer (score 0):

It refers to importing modules that are under the same parent directory.

In this directory structure:

```
parent
    module1
        __init__.py
        module1.py
    module2
        __init__.py
        module2.py
```

A sibling import for example would refer to importing `module1` from `module2.py`.